# c++14 static constexpr auto with odr usage

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, constexpr, auto

I have the following c++14 code:

```
template<typename T>
struct Test{
    static constexpr auto something{T::foo()};
};
```

This is perfectly fine, provided that `T::foo()` is a `constexpr` as well.

Now I have that `something` is ODR used, so I need to provide a namespace declaration. What syntax should I use?

```
template<typename T>
constexpr auto Test<T>::something;
```

Doesn't work.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you mean *a namespace declaration* - what you need is a *definition*.  And you'll need one for each `T` for which the template is instantiated.

Comment: Actually I mean a declaration. Since this is a contexpr, I need to define it in the class body.

Comment: `something` is a value. What do you want to achieve with this value in the expression like `constexpr auto 10`?

Comment: @S.M. I don't want to focus on this particular use case, I'm interested on the correct syntax to use on a situation like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about passing through a `using` defined typename ?

```
template <typename T>
struct Test
 {
   using someType = decltype(T::foo());

   static constexpr someType something{T::foo()};
 };

template<typename T>
constexpr typename Test<T>::someType Test<T>::something;
```

Comment: Yes, that's a viable workaround. I'd prefer to keep using the auto keyword though (if possible)

Comment: @Marieddu what's so important about using the auto keyword here?

Comment: @rtpax It's not so important. I will use this workaround if there is no way to do the same with auto.

Comment: I accept this answer as it seems there are no alternatives